# Disk Space Consuming of Docker Container Storage

Tags: image, docker, containers, storage, docker-container

I am a new comer in Docker.
Here is a question about the disk space of container storage
Say I pull a oraclelinux:7.3 to my local env, and the size of it is 225MB,

```
[root@slc08acl limtan]# docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
oraclelinux  7.3   d42df3cd808c   2 months ago        225 MB
```

And the storage location of image and container is:

```
[root@slc08acl limtan]# du -h --max-depth=1 /scratch/docker/overlay/
238M    /scratch/docker/overlay/ef25892fbf737bcebd42be6090f8828cea3a38f99ade782b772549145dfc42b6
238M    /scratch/docker/overlay/
```

Now, I would like to start two containers. Per my understanding from this [link](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/1520), the major difference between a container and an image is the top writable layer.
The disk space consuming will be around 238M = image(238M) + two writable layers,
because the two containers shared the same files. And the extra space consuming is their writable layers.

Now I created two containers and check the disk space,

```
[root@slc08acl limtan]# docker run -itd d42df3cd808c
23f310035a66691f9ec2ea18f648a56c09adc8a51435b3357242136905f17846
[root@slc08acl limtan]# docker run -itd d42df3cd808c
d6c27c6190844d2f78e43ae53115837fc979252cd67e5c28aae09f48691a1e68
[root@slc08acl limtan]# du -h --max-depth=1 /scratch/docker/overlay/
238M    /scratch/docker/overlay/df7480d641c62b61c5b5912420632f81e2f112ed42b2afa6519f1a15a2a02d22
227M    /scratch/docker/overlay/582cbe9a3c12be8d46323ad5d6efcf6e42261985b01d0e093f4a72083f05bd10
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/df7480d641c62b61c5b5912420632f81e2f112ed42b2afa6519f1a15a2a02d22-init
227M    /scratch/docker/overlay/ef25892fbf737bcebd42be6090f8828cea3a38f99ade782b772549145dfc42b6
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/582cbe9a3c12be8d46323ad5d6efcf6e42261985b01d0e093f4a72083f05bd10-init
692M    /scratch/docker/overlay/
```

(Seem that two containers take 692MB)

When I stop the container and check again

```
[root@slc08acl limtan]# docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
d6c27c619084
23f310035a66
[root@slc08acl limtan]# du -h --max-depth=1 /scratch/docker/overlay/
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/df7480d641c62b61c5b5912420632f81e2f112ed42b2afa6519f1a15a2a02d22
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/582cbe9a3c12be8d46323ad5d6efcf6e42261985b01d0e093f4a72083f05bd10
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/df7480d641c62b61c5b5912420632f81e2f112ed42b2afa6519f1a15a2a02d22-init
238M    /scratch/docker/overlay/ef25892fbf737bcebd42be6090f8828cea3a38f99ade782b772549145dfc42b6
40K     /scratch/docker/overlay/582cbe9a3c12be8d46323ad5d6efcf6e42261985b01d0e093f4a72083f05bd10-init
238M    /scratch/docker/overlay/
```

(Now the disk space taking return to 238MB)

From the above result, I have following questions:

1. Why the two containers take 692 MB? It seems containers copy all the files from the image
2. For the item /scratch/docker/overlay/ef25892fbf737bcebd42be6090f8828cea3a38f99ade782b772549145dfc42b6, why the size will change from 238M -> 227M after we start the containers
3. Why the disk space consuming will be different when the containers are in run/stop?

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you did not count some files twice (because they were loop mounted)? What does `df` show?